# JPopupMenu appears but seems to not react

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

I've problems to get a JPopupMenu working correctly.

**What I expect**

The menu should pop up once I do a right click with my mouse. Then I can select an item from the menu and do whatever I want..

**What I actually get**

The menu appears once I do a right click but after that I can not select a menu item or at least I am missing the well known mouse hover highlight effect (I would expect that the item I am currently hovering is highlighted, like it is the case in the normal menu).

The see problem here (no highlight on hover):

[image]

Here is my example code:

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject2;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PopupMenuTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        
        popup.add(new JMenuItem("A"));
        popup.add(new JMenuItem("B"));
        
        pane.setSize(300,300);
        pane.add(popup);
        pane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    popup.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
                    popup.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
         });
        
        frame.setTitle("Test");
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Compare to a "normal" menu with working hovering:

[image]

**Edit #2**

Please see the current (unexpected) behaviour:

[image]

Comment: It works as you coded...What do you expect ?

Comment: Hi @Joe as I wrote: I would expect that if I am hovering e.g. over the menu item "A" or "B" that this one is highlighted. I've updated my question.

Comment: I've had a similar problem recently with a JPopupMenu showing on tray icon click. In my case, changing setVisible to show in the accepted answer did not help. Instead, you have to call setInvoker(), It works even when setting the popup as the invoker itself: popup.setInvoker(popup); After adding this, the items are highlighted on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `JPopupMenu` `show` method, rather than the `setVisible` method.

Here's the code I tested with.  I'm running Windows 10 and using the Java JDK 13.0.2 with Java 8 compliance. I get the highlight on the mouse over.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JPopupMenuTest implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JPopupMenuTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        pane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
                    popup.add(new JMenuItem("A"));
                    popup.add(new JMenuItem("B"));

                    popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
        });

        frame.setTitle("JPopupMenu Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(pane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```